# How can i use Castle.ActiveRecord in WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-activerecord

I have a Silverlight application, a WCF service with a class library with ActiveRecord entities

I need to load a list of entities from the class library in the WCF service and send it to the Silverlight application

1. How do I initialise ActiveRecordStarter in service and establish connection to DB?
2. How do I provide ar:sessionScope?
3. How do I do lazy loads?

Thanks for any help and any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try to send your entities through WCF service.

Create dedicated data contract and map your entities to that contract.
Then you can use AR like in any other kind of application.
You could use custom `IParameterInspector` to open and close session scope if you're not using Windsor.

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer. but how to use ActiveRecordStarter in service ?

Comment: perhaps the easiest option would be in static constructor of your ServiceHostFactory class if you're not using something else to manage lifecycle of your service.

Comment: thanks, the static constructor really works! could you explain how to use properties with BelongsToAttribute when Lazy = FetchWhen.OnInvoke ? its always said then the session is null

Comment: I suggest you ask the question on Castle users group